# The provided key element does not match the schema. GraphQL Mutation error

Tags: react-native

I am trying to test/run a mutation that creates groupChat in my DynamoDB by id,groupChatName, messages, createdTime, createdUser, users. I have 2 seperate tables, UserTable and GroupChatTable.The problem is I keep getting data is null and an error that says "the provided key element does not match the schema. ErrorCode: Validation Exception, request ID." Resolvers are attached to my tables so I am not sure why I am getting this error.

The weird thing is when I check the groupChatTable, my mutation is saved incorrectly as an input.This is what it looks like,
Ex: {"createdTime":{"S":"12:00"},"createdUser":{"S":"Me"},........

Below is the Mutation,Schema type,and Resolver.

````
    createGroupChat(input:{
        id: 4
        groupChatName: "newgroup"
        messages: "we love this group"
        createdTime:"12:00"
        createdUser: "Me"
        users:"we, me"
    }) {
    id
    groupChatName
    messages
    createdTime
    createdUser
    users
  }
}```
```type GroupChat {
    id: ID!
    groupChatName: String!
    messages: String
    createdTime: String!
    createdUser: String!
    users: String
}```
```{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "id": $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()),
    },
    "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args)
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way data is being stored through resolver is incorrect and when it returns it doesn't match the schema

Instead of using $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson(($ctx.args))

use: $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($util.parseJson($util.toJson($ctx.args.input)))

Comment: I will post it now

Comment: "attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args)

change this to

"attributeValues" : $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($ctx.args.input)

Comment: $util.dynamodb.toMapValuesJson($util.parseJson($util.toJson($ctx.args.input))), try this one